# Let be $E = \{ (x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^{3} \ | \ z = 0 \} ⊂ \mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Let be $E = \{ (x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb{R}^{3} \ | \ z = 0 \} ⊂ \mathbb{R}^3$.
Prove that the endomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f(x, y, z) = (−x − 3y, −3x − y + 2z, 2z)$ let $E$ invariant. Caluculate a basis of $E$ and the marix of restriction $f_{|E}$ of $f$ in the same basis. Calculate all the endomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that can be diagonalizable, leave $E$ invariant and match with $f$ over $E$.**

My attemp,

$ \forall u \in E$, $f(u) = (a,b,0) \in E$, with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(E)⊂E $

Let $\mathscr{B}$ a basis of E, then $\mathscr{B}= \{ (1,0,0), (0,1,0) \} $.

Now, for the matrix of restriction we need the transformed vector of $\mathscr{B}$ on the same basis.

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -3 & 0\\
-3 & -1 & 2\\
 0 & 0  & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

$ [ f(1,0,0)]_{\mathscr{B}} = (-1,-3) $

$ [ f(0,1,0)]_{\mathscr{B}} = (-3,-1) $

\begin{equation}
A_{f_{|E}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -3\\
-3 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

We can see that $f$ is not diagonalizable.

So now, how can I calculate all the endomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the given conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is not diagonalizable. And endomorphisms of $\Bbb R^3$ that can be diagonalizable, leave $E$ invariant and match with $f$ over $E$ are those whose matrix with respect to the standard basis is of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-3&0\\-3&-1&0\\0&0&t\end{bmatrix},$$for some $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: But, for instance, for $t=2$ the endomorphism is not diagonalizable. I guess you mean for some $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $t\neq 2$, is that? Anyway, which is the reason?

Comment: Why do you say that? Yes, it is diagonalizable even when $t=2$. *Every* real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. The only peculiar thing about the case in which $t=2$ is that then $2$ will be a double root of the characteristic polynomial. So what?

Comment: Yeah! You right! I've confused that matrix with the previous one. And what do you say about that same matrix, but with $ a_{23} = k $ for some $k$ and $t$ $\in \mathbb{R}$? It's also valid?

Comment: Those will also work, unless $t=2$ or $t=-4$.

Comment: OK! Thx that was so helpful ;)